# What does "at the individual scale" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Our special series “Out of Work in America” tells the stories of unemployed Americans in their own words. For this project, The Times’s National desk collaborated with 11 local news organizations in the U.S. Here’s what Jia Lynn Yang, a deputy editor on the National desk, and Clinton Cargill, an assistant editor, said about these accounts from a dozen people.
>
> Q. The National Desk has more than 40 reporters scattered across the country, but over the last year, Marc Lacey, the National editor, has prioritized partnerships with local news organizations, as with this project.
>
> A. Clinton: Local news organizations have a special authority in the communities they cover. They know the big employers, the community groups, the state and local policies that make all the difference for people seeking unemployment. We thought they could bring some of that depth **at the individual scale.**

I don't exactly understand what the part marked in stars mean here.

What does "individual" refer to? is it the interviewees ("a dozen people" who are unemployed)? or is it the editors? What does the phrase "at the individual scale" as a whole mean in this context?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a good answer already on the meaning, but assuming this is from an extemporaneous interview it's probably just poor word choice that they phrased it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is the preceding sentence:

> They know the big employers, the community groups, the state and local policies that make all the difference for people seeking unemployment.

The local press already covers these groups and organizations. What they do not currently cover in their news stories are *individuals*, which is the new series they're launching.

So, *to bring some depth... at an individual scale*, is talking about the reporters bringing more reporting depth and coverage to the topic of individuals (currently out of work).

You might also say something like:

- We thought they could bring some of that depth **at the individual level**.

I would argue that "bring depth... at" is a weird collocation. Usually, you bring depth **to** something.  To say this more clearly, I would argue the following:

> We thought they could bring some of that depth to cover the lives and struggles of individuals in our communities.

or

> We thought they could bring some of that depth to cover the lives and struggles within our communities at a more personal/individual level.